# Android App Project stop compiling, error in grade.build

Tags: android, gradle

i'm new to gradle, and I'm starting with my first steps in Android.

Until yesterday I was able to compile and test my Android App, when suddenly stoped compiling with  this error when I click on "Debug 'app'"

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\ATMobile\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2508: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\ATMobile\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2509: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

This is my grade.buil (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
//    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ar.com.codigose.atmobile"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0 BETA"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //buildToolsVersion '29.0.0 rc1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.nbsp:library:1.8'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
}
```

I commented *buildToolsVersion* tag, because I saw in my github the original file, and it doesn't have that line.

and this grade.buil (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I want to keep developing in sdk 26, but I can't see what is wrong.

In the ide, the line : 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

is underlined and said that found something with version 28.0.0, but I have nothing with that version.

What is going on ??
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you're building this app on a different Android SDK version than the original file, this Udacity link may be helpful (note section of the page):

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7633778648/concepts/2eef07a4-abb3-448f-8025-8aeb7cf21621

Comment: hello @abouzar_j , sorry but  can't reach section!

Answer (score 0):

resolved, the problem was that I added the new feature or Navigator Fragment to one of my activities... and everything goes to the toilet!...

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Let see in your gradle-wrapper.properties that your gradle version should
be minimum of 4.10.1 for classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

**`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`**

Hope this will work.